# Bootstrap thumbnails on multiple pages

Tags: html, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, jinja2, thumbnails

I have set up a flask web app using bootstrap to style it. I have set it up so that specific images appear in the thumbnails. When the app is run the images do not appear in the thumbnails on all the specified html pages.

I have included the html which contains the thumbnails which load the images. I have also included the html which contains the thumbnails where the images do not appear.  Thank you in advanced.

---

HTML with thumbnails that load images :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>

Recipes

 | Baking Recipe Catalogue</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Baking Recipe Catalogue">
<meta name="author" content="Joanna Mein">
<link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/static/js/recipes.json" rel="json" />

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:5000/">Baking Recipes</a> </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes">Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/add_recipe">Add Recipe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="img_cont"> 


<div class="img_cont bg_img">
    <h1 class="banner">Baking Recipes</h1>
    <h2 class="banner">Here you can find recipes depending on occasion or baking time</h2>
</div>


</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
        <h3 class="recipe_title">Find recipe by</h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Occasion </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/halloween/">Halloween</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/bonfire/">Bonfire Night</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/christmas/">Christmas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Baking Time </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/10_mins/">Less than 10 Minutes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/10_20mins/">10 - 20 Minutes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/20_30mins/">20 - 30 Minutes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/30_40mins/">30 - 40 Minutes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-10 main'> 


<h3>All Recipes</h3>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../static/imgs/pumpkin_pie.png" alt="Pumpkin Pie">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Pumpkin Pie</h3>
        <p>Serves: 8</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: 30 mins to 1 hour</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/pumpkin_pie" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../static/imgs/cobweb_cake.png" alt="Cobweb Cake">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Marshmallow Cobweb Cake</h3>
        <p>Serves: 10</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: 30 mins to 1 hour</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/cobweb_cake" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../static/imgs/rocky_road.png" alt="Rocky Road">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Rocky Road Crunch Bars</h3>
        <p>Serves: 24</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: less than 10 mins</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/rocky_road" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../static/imgs/peanut_squares.png" alt="Peanut Squares">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Peanut Butter Squares</h3>
        <p>Serves: 16</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: 10 to 30 mins</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/peanut_squares" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../static/imgs/toffee_muffins.png" alt=" Toffee Muffins">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Toffee Apple Muffins</h3>
        <p>Serves: 12</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: 30 mins to 1 hour</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/toffee_muffins" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../static/imgs/christmas_wreath.png" alt=" Christmas Wreath">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Christmas Wreath Biscuits</h3>
        <p>Serves: 18</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: 10 mins to 30 mins</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/christmas_wreaths" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../static/imgs/gingerbread_baubles.png" alt=" Gingerbread Baubles">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Gingerbread Baubles</h3>
        <p>Serves: 15</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: 10 mins to 30 mins</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/gingerbread_baubles" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../static/imgs/mince_pies.png" alt=" Mince Pies">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Easy Mince Pies</h3>
        <p>Serves: 18</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: 10 mins to 30 mins</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/mince_pies" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Set09103 Coursework1 - Recipe Catalouge</p>
        <p>Joanna Mein</p>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

HTML that doesn't load images:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Halloween
 | Baking Recipe Catalogue</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Baking Recipe Catalogue">
<meta name="author" content="Joanna Mein">
<link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/static/js/recipes.json" rel="json" />

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:5000/">Baking Recipes</a> </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes">Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/add_recipe">Add Recipe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="img_cont"> 

<div class="img_cont bg_img1">
    <h1 class="banner">Halloween Recipes</h1>
</div>

</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
        <h3 class="recipe_title">Find recipe by</h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Occasion </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/halloween/">Halloween</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/bonfire/">Bonfire Night</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/christmas/">Christmas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Baking Time </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/10_mins/">Less than 10 Minutes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/10_20mins/">10 - 20 Minutes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/20_30mins/">20 - 30 Minutes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/30_40mins/">30 - 40 Minutes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-10 main'> 

<h3>All Halloween Recipies</h3>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="" alt="Pumpkin Pie">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Pumpkin Pie</h3>
        <p>Serves: 8</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: 30 mins to 1 hour</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/pumpkin_pie" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../static/imgs/cobweb_cake.png" alt="Cobweb Cake">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Marshmallow Cobweb Cake</h3>
        <p>Serves: 10</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: 30 mins to 1 hour</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/halloween/cobweb_cake" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_fluid" "row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../static/imgs/rocky_road.png" alt="Rocky Road">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Rocky Road Crunch Bars</h3>
        <p>Serves: 24</p>
        <p>Cooking Time: less than 10 mins</p>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/recipes/halloween/rocky_road" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Set09103 Coursework1 - Recipe Catalouge</p>
        <p>Joanna Mein</p>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

[It should appear like this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3StBa.jpg)

[But instead appears like this on all the other pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLnnO.png)

Comment: do you have the online preview page?

Comment: Im using python flask to display the site so its just local host

Comment: can you try open your developer tools in your browser and copy the html from there?

Comment: Full html has been added

Comment: Can you double check if all your images`<img src="../static/imgs/cobweb_cake.png" alt="Cobweb Cake">` is linking to the right directory?

Comment: Take a look at this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218745/python-flask-jinja-image-file-not-found

Comment: Thanks this worked

Comment: You are welcome, please vote up if you find my replies useful.